# Что такое "масштабируемость"?

Tags: веб-программирование, терминология, масштабирование

Что имеется в виду в контексте программирования, когда, например, говорят, что приложение должно быть масштабируемым? Приведите конкретные примеры для понимания.

Comment: Лёгкость внесения изменений при увеличении какой-то метрики. Чаще всего имеют в виду количество активных соединений и количество запросов в секунду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно под "масштабируемостью" имеют в виду, что решение (это не только сама программа, но и инфраструктура для неё - БД, железо, на котором крутится БД и серверная часть и т.д.) может быть относительно легко (без смены архитектуры) переделано под сильно увеличившееся количество запросов/пользователей/объёмов данных/и т.д. просто количественным добавлением каких-то дополнительных ресурсов.

То есть вот написали люди, например, сайт, который способен обслуживать 5 посетителей одновременно. Скорее всего он справится и с 20 посетителями. А вот "переварит" ли он 100 посетителей или 1000 одновременно?

Если такое изменение посещаемости не приведёт к тому, что сайт станет работать очень медленно или вообще "впадёт в ступор", а он **будет продолжать работать эффективно при принятии неких заранее оговоренных мер** по достижении некоего порога посещаемости - например, если для этого нужно будет только увеличить оперативную память или перевести сайт на немного более мощный по CPU сервер, то говорят, что такое решение **масштабируемо**.

А вот если чтобы обслуживать 100 и тем более 1000 пользователей недостаточно будет принять простые меры по увеличению мощностей, а нужно будет **переписывать ПО, мигрировать на другую БД, добавлять какие-то новые программные и аппаратные решения**, то тогда говорят, что используемое решение **не масштабируемо** - оно способно работать только в каких-то определённых узких рамках, при выходе за которые это решение нужно будет фактически заново разрабатывать уже под другие количества/объёмы пользователей/данных/и т.д.

Хотя вопрос о том, насколько узкие или широкие должны быть эти рамки, в которых работает конкретное решение, чтобы можно было его назвать маштабируемым или наоборот не масштабируемым - это уже вопрос довольно субъективный. Всё-таки многие вещи имеют определённые пределы, например, оперативную память невозможно наращивать до бесконечности, как и процессорную мощность. Но если решение способно выдержать планируемое увеличение нагрузки на несколько порядков и способно "переварить" нагрузку, запланированную на него бизнесом на несколько лет вперёд - думаю, его можно называть масштабируемым.

Answer (score 1):

**Первое правило работы с непонятными словами** - попробовать **перевести их на русский язык**, а затем избавиться от них.

"Масштаб" - это немецкое слово Maßstab, написанное русскими буквами, которое обозначает "размер" ("шкалу", тоже немецкое слово Skala) для измерения (отображения) чего-либо. По-английски scale (не совпадение).

"Масштабируемость" (англ "scalability") в переводе на русский обозначает "расширяемость", т.е. изменение размера.

Применительно к приложениям под расширяемостью подразумевают:

- лёгкое добавление новых возможностей в существующее приложение (гибкость);
- возможность увеличения задействованных производительных мощностей (наращивание);
- возможность одновременной работы нескольких человек над одной большой задачей, путём разбиения её на подзадачи для каждого участника (разделение).

ПС. **Второе правило работы с непонятными словами - не использовать непонятные слова.**